# jQuery Datepicker unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I add a datepicker with jQuery datepicker and make use of the altFormat '@' --> see http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

```
 // Function datepicker
        $("#obsDate").datepicker({
            altField: '#actualDate',
            altFormat: '@',        // Gives a timestamp dateformat
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: $("#datePickerImg").val(),
            buttonImageOnly: true,
        });
```

When the user picks a value the unix timestamp is set.
Like : 1312840800000

This is  in miliseconds so i id do /1000

But when i convert the timestamp with the function in C#

```
private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
        {
            var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp);
        }
```

I get always one day ealier..

What i'm doing wrong?

**UPDATED:**
When i use the build in function of javascript gettime()

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000));
```

I get the right timestamp...

- Example with getTime() i get:
  30-08-2011 --> 1314628036

Example with the datepicker i get :
29-08-2011 --> 1314568800.

This is also with ticks (!) in the datepicker.

Comment: have you tried `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);`?

Comment: What language is your second code snippet in?

Comment: Maybe its because of sumemr/wintertime or another timezone ont he client? It owuld be enough to get 1 second wrong here, to jump a day backwards, when you set it on 00:00:00.

Comment: Does `new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, timestamp)` give the right date?

Comment: i tried with new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) but it didn't work out, i got a year from 1970

Comment: This is what I needed, Thanks! var ts = Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000));

Comment: I would discourage passing doubles and splitting the conversions between JavaScript and server code.

Answer (score 4):

This obviously *IS* a timezone problem.

`getTime()`
This function returns milliseconds since 'epoch', meaning you get `Unix timestamp * 1000` as seen from local computer.
See [If javascript “(new Date()).getTime()” is run from 2 different Timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577823/if-javascript-new-date-gettime-is-run-from-2-different-timezones).

`datepicker({altFormat: '@'})`
From what I see in `jQuery` library, `datepicker` internally uses `formatDate` function, that takes timezone into account
(I started here: [jQuery.datepicker.formatDate and timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754740/jquery-datepicker-formatdate-and-timezone-offset)...)

So, on my PC I get 2 hours difference.
I can't think of an easy way to resolve this, but you could try the following:
[datetimepicker getDate to return Date / Time in UTC format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533490/datetimepicker-getdate-to-return-date-time-in-utc-format)

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that .NET doesn't know what timezone it is. You will have to define this.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your code you must do next:

```
    private static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(double timestamp)
    {
        var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return origin.AddSeconds(timestamp - origin.getTime());
    }
```

This is because Jan 1th in most of the timezones is correspond to a unixtime value that is greater than zero or one. So, more correctly you must set (not add) the timestamp to the `Datetime` object (if you have a setter).

Answer (score 0):

### Round Trip Precision

Unix times (milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970) are less precise than .Net DateTime's so for round-trip to .Net code,  or if comparing to a .Net DateTime, this is the precision to expect. E.g. .Net -> Unix -> .Net can be off by this amount.

```
var unixEpochPrecision = new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
```

It might not really matter, but you should at least be aware of it.

### Convert to Unix Epoch milliseconds

UTC dates are required when you start, or you will otherwise be off by a few hours. This makes sense because Unix times, irrespective of time zone, are always expressed in UTC. If only .net was that way.

```
DateTime UnixEpochBaseDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

Int64 ToUnixTime(DateTime utcValue)
{
    if (utcValue.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
        throw new ArgumentException("Value must be in Utc.");

    var result = (utcValue - UnixEpochBaseDate).Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    return result;
}
```

### Convert from Unix Epoch to CLR DateTime

Just use the milliseconds as-is. This makes the JavaScript easier to code also.

```
DateTime ToClrDateTime(Int64 unixEpochMilliseconds)
{
    var clrDateTime = UnixEpochBaseDate + 
        new TimeSpan(unixEpochMilliseconds * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
    return clrDateTime;
}
```

In JavaScript

```
var date = new Date(1381367291665);
```