# jQuery.datepicker.formatDate and timezone offset

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, timezone-offset

To handle dates, i'm using a jQuery UI `public` method in my application: jQuery.datepicker.formatDate
See params & source here : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js

However the wrong date is displayed sometimes, according to the computer timezone.

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/7ACdB/

With a UTC+1 (paris) timezone in windows, i got :

```
03/30/20
03/30/20
```

With a UTC-6 (us&canada) timezone in windows, i got :

```
03/29/20 <- meh!
03/30/20
```

You need to restart your browser (well for google chrome at least) when you change the OS timezone.

My problem is the "03/29/20" date as you can imagine.

Can somebody explains to me if this is normal or a jquery ui issue ?

I'm beginning to think that it is normal to see a "Mon Mar 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)" as 03/29/20 in a US timezone but i'm not so sure. :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're getting is correct. Your example sets the time at midnight for Paris. Midnight in Paris is 6PM the day **before** in the US for the Eastern Time Zone which I am in.

Your first time: GMT+0200 is Paris

Your second time: GMT-0500 is Chicago (note it is currently Daylight Savings Time)

So, when you change the time zone to US (using one of our [6 time zones](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/usa/)), the output is the time in the US when is **that time** in Paris.

Here is an updated fiddle with a the time set to 6 AM Paris: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/7ACdB/1/

Comment: re, thank you for your answer. As my understanding of timezones improved, I've come to the same conclusion for this. My issue was in fact a little more complex: the date was decreasing of 1 day each time the blur event was emitted. When that event occurs, I'm using jQuery.datepicker.parseDate & jQuery.datepicker.formatDate methods which work in local time. But then I was saving the date object returned by parseDate... I managed to sort this out using setUTCFullYear & new Date(dateV.getUTCFullYear(), dateV.getUTCMonth(), dateV.getUTCDate()) at correct places.