# datetimepicker getDate to return Date / Time in UTC format

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I happen to read this [datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) addon and found it to be of great use. The issue that I am facing using this tool is that I am unable to get data / time format in UTC or other formats (my intention is to at least get date / time in UTC format:

```
$('#starttime').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true,
    showHour: true,
    showMinute: true,
    showSecond: false,
    showMillisec: false,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
    hourGrid: 4,
    stepHour: 1,
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    stepMinute: 10
 });
```

The below script prints me data / time in below format:

```
var startDt = $('#starttime').datetimepicker('getDate');

Tue May 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How can I change this format to any other like

DD-MM-YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY or in UTC format?

Answer (score 4):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dgnjn/2/

**or**

dd-mm-yy here http://jsfiddle.net/Dgnjn/5/

Now using **`datetimepicker`**

The important thing to note in the sample below is:

```
dateAsObject = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(dateAsObject))
```

**code**

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    //altField: '#alternate',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
    stepHour: 2,
    stepMinute: 10,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method
     dateAsObject = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(dateAsObject))
        $('#alternate').val(dateAsObject);
       // alert(dateAsObject + '==> ' + $('#alternate').val());
   }

});
```

Comment: But I am using datetimepicker not datepicker. datetimepicker addon allows me to get both data and time

Comment: @Prakash saweet bruv, take look now, changed it for datetimepicker now for demo, have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: css and js links in fiddles are not found anymore.

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the date formats:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats

```
$('#starttime').datetimepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

Comment: Even after adding this dateFormat option when I use  $('#starttime').datetimepicker('getDate'); I get date / time in format as in Tue May 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: `$('#starttime').datepicker().datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy").change(function(){
   alert($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy',  $('#starttime').datepicker('getDate')));
  });;`