# ASP.NET MVC binding query to DateTime

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have an URL like this:

```
http://localhost/TestWeb/TestPage?dateFrom=2013-10-10T22:00:00.000Z&dateTo=2013-10-17T22:00:00.000Z
```

And action like this:

```
public ActionResult TestPage(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    //do something
}
```

As you can se from the URL, I am passing DateTime as UTC, but something (ModelBinder?) is converting that DateTime to a local DateTime.

Is this the default behavior? Can I always assume that DateTime objects will be converted to local time?

Comment: The ModelBinder will parse the date based on your server / os configuration

Comment: I think this will help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/utc-timestamp-in-javascript