# Javascript vs Date

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have some interesting problem and can't find the solution. Look at this:

```
var d1 = new Date("07 31 2014");
document.write(d1);
document.write('<br />');
var d2 = new Date(1406746800 * 1000);
document.write(d2);
```

when I run this script I get this result:

```
Thu Jul 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (UZT)
Thu Jul 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (UZT)
```

then  after I changed my time zone I get this result:

```
Thu Jul 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (AKDT)
Wed Jul 30 2014 11:00:00 GMT-0800 (AKDT)
```

as you can see the second result is Jul 30, but first result is Jul 31. I think they must both be equal to 31 Jul. I know this problem depends on the timezone but is there a solution?

Comment: Hello - i guess its Thursday 31 00:00 but with +0500 in that specific Timezone. So if you calculate with this Timestamp for another Date with -0800 you should get the Date 13 Hours before ( from 24:00 - 13 = 11:00) - and so if your calculating with a Timestamp for a Specific ZimeZone you get different Values

Comment: Use UTC dates maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/utc-timestamp-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

So the constructor parameter is:

> an Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1
>   January 1970 00:00:00 UTC

So given your integer value, that represents (for me, in BST):

```
Wed Jul 30 2014 20:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Which is

```
Wed Jul 30 2014 19:00:00 UTC
```

And your timezone is GMT-8, so thats the above -8 which gives:

```
Wed Jul 30 2014 11:00:00 GMT-0800 AKDT
```

The *date string* constructor constructs the date in your local timezone. You can see what the value should be by doing this:

```
new Date("07 31 2014").getTime() / 1000
```

Which returns `1406761200`, not `1406746800`