# JS parse time without timezone

Tags: javascript

There is the following code:

```
new Date("2000-01-01T18:00:00.000Z")
```

I got:

```
Date {Sat Jan 01 2000 21:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)}
```

But I need to get:

```
Date {Sat Jan 01 2000 18:00:00}
```

i.e. time without specific timezone. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: did not you get the right datetime object? it is just displayed with timezone information, you can change the display.

Comment: `date.split(' GMT').shift()`

Comment: It's data from backend, I can't change it.

Comment: To clarify: is the time zone in the original string wrong? What would be the correct time zone then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript

Comment: If you just want GMT time, there's like ten duplicates on how to do that ?

Comment: As you can see original String doesn't contain any timezone, but new Date('...') create a date with browser time zone. I don't need to do it. Is it good?

Comment: The original string doesn't contain any time zone? How about `Z`?

Comment: That's beacuse javascript uses local time, and you're passing in an UTC timestamp.

Comment: adeneo, I understand. How can I convert without using local time, i.e. UTC?

Comment: I don't need String, I need Date object!

Comment: again, you already have a date object. just display it with GMT timezone: `var d=new Date("2000-01-01T18:00:00.000Z"); console.log(d.toUTCString())`

Comment: I dont need a string, I need a Date object!