# Get timestamp of current hour in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible for me to get the UTC time of current hour in Javascript?

I've tried the following:

```
var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
var hours = new Date().getHours();
var hourStamp = new Date().setHours(hours, 0,0,0);
var dates = new Date(hourStamp);
```

Here `dates` gives me the Unix Timestamp of the current hour. Is there a better/faster way to do this?

EDIT:

For example: I want the Timestamp for the current hour. So if it's 00:16 am on 12/04/2015, I want the timestamp of `12/04/2015 00:00`. And, my method works. My question pertains to if there's a better method of doing the same.

Comment: Also see [How do I get a UTC timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: @TylerH, I'm not sure if this is a duplicate. I know how to get a Unix Timestamp. I'm not sure you understood my question. Edited question

Comment: Why do you get the minutes?

Comment: @Newtt If your code is working and you are looking for improvements, CodeReview.StackExchange is the place to ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var UTCHour = new Date().getUTCHours();
```

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

The one works well:

```
var UTCTime= (new Date()).toUTCString();
```