# convert Javascript timestamp into UTC format

Tags: javascript, timestamp

For example if you receive a timestamp in Javascript:

1433454951000

How would you create a function to convert the timestamp into UTC like:

2015/6/4 GMT+7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date <- in the documentation, value can be _Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch)._ , like your seems to be. After creating the date object you can really do everything you want with such, including printing that as a timestamp into UTC, perhaps you can even think about a DateTime object... And.. this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString

Answer (score 0):

```
var d1 = new Date("UNIX TIME STAMP HERE");
d1.toUTCString()
```

Originally asked here:
[How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)