# How should I get GMT time as integer

Tags: javascript

Would this be correct ?

```
function getGMT() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    return currentTime.getTime() + currentTime.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
}
```

in particular **is it correct to add the offset or should it be subtracted** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: not duplicate, I'm after GMT not UTC

Comment: Actually, GMT is UTC.

Comment: GMT is a time zone and UTC is a time standard (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html) ... Sorry I cannot understand from the other question how to get GMT as integer without accessing a remote server.

Comment: `is it correct to add the offset or should it be subtracted` - neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
return currentTime.getTime()
```

Comment: as an example - `console.log(new Date('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z').getTime())` will log `0`

Comment: I thought getTime returns current time and not GMT

Comment: @JaromandaX and `console.log(new Date('1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00').getTime())` too.

Comment: @Supersharp - which proves that time is being stored as a GMT offset

Comment: @kofifus - when in doubt, read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) ... you could equally use `.valueOf()` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
function getGMT() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    return currentTime.getTime() + currentTime.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
    document.getElementById("wtf").innerHTML = currentTime.getHours();
}
```

it will spit out a number between `0`-`23`

maybe i don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I need the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 like getTime ... so you're saying adding the offset is the correct way ?

Comment: no it is not correct to add or subtract the timezone offset. Dates are "stored" as milliseconds since 1 jan 1970 0:00:00 GMT