# When converting a JSON DateTime to a JavaScript date it is showing as 1 day previous than the local timezone

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, datetime

I am making an AJAX request like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetExpirationDates", "Products")',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    var dateArray = data.map(function (date) {
        var d = new Date(date);
        return d.toLocaleDateString();
    });
});
```

Here is what `data` looks likes:

> 2016-02-25T00:00:00,2016-03-25T00:00:00,2016-04-25T00:00:00

It seems that as soon as I do `new Date(date)` each one of these dates has a chance of showing as

> 2/24/2016, 3/24/2016, 4/24/2016

(one day less than it should be) depending on what the local time is. I am aware that this is most likely due to the way JavaScript handles timezones. I am wondering how to go about fixing it.

Comment: I recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to more easily deal with dates.  The timezone issues and many other things are much more gracefully handled.  Another hack would be to add 12 hours to each Date.

Comment: +1 for moment.js. Also read up on UTC datetime handling to help avid all sorts of complexity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to consume the end result.
A simple example is:

```
var d = new Date("2016-02-25T00:00:00");
d.getDate(); //returns 24 because my timezone is -06:00.
d.getUTCDate(); //returns 25, the UTC day of the month
```

The same can be done for getMonth/getUTCMonth

I would really suggest using moment. Where its as easy as

```
moment("2016-02-25T00:00:00").format("MM/DD/YYYY"); //returns "02/25/2016"
```

It gives you finer control over UTC and formatting strings.

Comment: So how can I go from: var d = new Date("2016-02-25T00:00:00"); to a formatted date string of "2/25/2016"?

Comment: I came down to me doing the following: Is this really what has to be done? (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getUTCDate() + '/' +  d.getFullYear()

Comment: Javascript doesn't really have a format function for string. Also if using toUTCDate make sure you use toUTCMonth and toUTCFullYear or your month/year could be off on days near month end/start.
I really recomment using Moment.js if you want to work with dates much.
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: If i use moment.js is it really that easy to always display dates in the proper time zone? What function would I use in my case?

Comment: Added example to my answer!

Comment: That worked perfectly. Moment automatically handles this problem? Is the moment-with-locale required for this functionality or can I just use the standard moment

Comment: Locales is just for non-english display strings I believe. What I did was with base moment library. I would highly recommend scanning their docs just to familiarize yourself with what its capable of.

Comment: Whats happening here is that in the absence of a timezone, moment is treating that string as localtime, not utc. So formatting it out the date stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
function getNow() {
    var date = new Date(),
        y = date.getFullYear(),
        mo = date.getMonth() + 1,
        d  = date.getDate(),
        h = date.getHours(),
        m  = date.getMinutes(),
        s  = date.getSeconds();

    date.setDate(date.getDate());
    mo = (mo < 10 ? '0' : '') +  mo;
    d = (d < 10 ? '0' : '') + d;
    h = (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h;
    m = (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m;
    s = (s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s;

    return h + ':' + m + ':' + s + ' - ' + mo + '/' + d + '/' + y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a UTC offset when using ISO8601 date strings, the browser will assume that the date is UTC.

Representing this as a locale date string will apply the offset according to your timezone.

If you want to get the UTC date, you can use

```
return d.toUTCString();
```

Alternatively, if you have control over the JSON service, you can specify a timezone which the dates belong to in the ISO string.

For example, UTC - 7 hours would be represented as.

> 2016-02-25T00:00:00-0700,2016-03-25T00:00:00-0700,2016-04-25T00:00:00-0700

If your local timezone is UTC - 7 hours, d.toLocaleString would correctly show as

> 2/25/2016, 3/25/2016, 4/25/2016

Comment: I find it best to let the service always return and accept UTC dates.  Let the client javascript do the convertion of times to local time zones and back to UTC.

Comment: So how can I get the local date string in the format like 2/23/2016? Would it be something like new Date(date.toLocaleString()); ?