# How to get correct UTC time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

I want to get current date UTC midnight:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d.toISOString())
```

This returns me:

```
2016-04-21T00:00:00.000Z
```

Is this UTC time? I think it is not and it should be:

```
2016-04-20T22:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: 00:00 is midnight, 22:00 is 10 pm. Why are you expecting the latter?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript Will give you more insight in this area.

Comment: Date handling in JS is basically evil in my opinion. Once you understand what is going on I recommend you checkout moment.js

Comment: @aray12—javascript (ECMAScript) Dates are very simple, they're just a time value. However, many have trouble understanding how time and dates work in general. A library can't help that. E.g. the OP wants "*…current date UTC midnight*", which I think of as the end of the day, but the OP seems to want the start of the day.

Comment: @RobG I agree he/she should first understand native JS dates, which is why I recommended he not move on to moment.js without figuring out what is going on. That said JS date and specifically timezone handling can be painful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have midnight of your time zone in UTC time then the code is as following:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d.toISOString());
```