# datetime UTC conversion in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I do `new Date()` then save it into mongodb, the date became UTC format?

The datetime I inserted into mongodb when pull back is not the same, what should I do to solve this? Like I create a document on 1/12/2016, and I select range from 1/12/2016, the record is not there. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Date/) says :

> The mongo shell wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper. The ISODate is in UTC.

So my best guess is that your `new Date()` is not in UTC.

`Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)`

as seen here: [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

However, Mongo is smart enough to sort this all out for you, so `new Date()` should be enough.

To query a Date in mongo, you can also use pure Date Objects, without the need to convert them to ISOString.

Keep everything as Date Objects, and it'll work as you intend it to!

Comment: so basically I can't do new Date() but Date.UTC(saved-timezone) if I want to use mongodb?

Comment: You shouldn't need that though, Mongo is clever enough to sort it all out for you. could you show us what you insert, and what is written in the mongo doc?

Comment: if that is the case why should I have that strange error?

Comment: maybe your query?

Comment: Are you sure? Can you help to take a look? http://pastebin.com/g7YEd7a5

Comment: yes, you're converting your dates with toIsoString(), you don't need to do that

Comment: so just return d? removing the firstDayOfMonth will solve my problem? are u sure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129504/discussion-between-xshirase-and-jessie-emerson).

Comment: my 2 function return this {"firstDayOfMonth":"2016-11-01T09:45:30.998Z","lastDayOfMonth":"2016-11-30T09:45:30.998Z"}. why is the range is so strange?

Answer (score 0):

The default timezone for node.js new Date() object is UTC (aka GMT).

You should leave it this way and just convert it on your front end. Javascript in the browser can convert the UTC timestamp to the browsers local timezone automatically.

```
new Date(Date.UTC(saved-timezone))
```

[How do you create a JavaScript Date object with a set timezone without using a string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s)

Comment: so basically I can't do new Date() but Date.UTC(saved-timezone) if I want to use mongodb?

Comment: You always want to save dates in UTC and then convert them to the local timezone after they are retrieved. Just leave it as UTC, and use the code above to translate the time into the local timezone after retrieval.

Comment: convert time in front end after retrieved?

Comment: If you want the local timezone of the browser to be displayed then yes.