# How get timestamp by UTC Date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone, gettime

i would to get `timestamp` by `UTC Date` in javascript. 
I searched and read other questions but i didn't find a solution.

I have this **UTC Date** `2017-07-16   12:00:07.8 UTC` but if i use `.getTime()`  it returns timestampt (milliseconds) in **UTC** removing another two hours.

I'm in Italy and here Date is **UTC+2**, maybe `.getTime()` read data with Italy timezone and when returns timestamp removing that 2 hours? Is it possible?

```
var data= new Date(2017,06,16,12,0,7);
var mill= data.getTime();

alert(mill);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1500199207
```

I hope you can help me and do not consider my question as duplicate.
Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: @AnuragSinghBisht IS NOT SAME QUESTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date.UTC()` instead of `new Date()`:

```
var mill= Date.UTC(2017,06,16,12,0,7);

alert(mill);
```

`new Date()` assumes the values provided are for the browser's current timezone

Answer (score 2):

You can use moment to do it:

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

or

Date object is working using UTC. You can add 2 hours in your case using new `Date().getTimezoneOffset();` (witch is negative (-120 in minutes))

Answer (score 1):

You have to first get your timezoneoffset and add that timezone diff. into data

```
var data = new Date(2017, 06, 16, 12, 0, 7);
var timestamp = -data.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
var mill = data.getTime();
mill = mill+timestamp;
```

Hope this will helpful for you.