# How to ignore javascript timezone to send a datetime to server

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, datepicker, timezone

I am building a web app with c# and angular to store event schedule. The user will input a date time which is in UTC and I want to save that time in db exactly as inputted. And then show exactly same time when a user will view this information. And this should not depend on user's timezone, and I am telling the user that time is in UTC.

But the problem is browser send time information with timezone info when ajax post to server and server saves a different time (by converting its own timezone) in db as the server is in a different timezone.

How to prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: May be no, as i want to send a date time without timezone info, i don't want to send it with UTC timezone info. Because when i send UTC time, server converts it to a new time if server not in UTC GMT 0 timezone.

Comment: Are you using html5 datetime input?

Comment: It's an angular date picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how you are formatting. But I think you could use momentjs in case you don't want to use any custom solution. The following code should work

> moment(your_date_time).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

in case your_date_time has time zone, then the following should work

> moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

Comment: Yes moment with first format did work there. Actually a given string format without timezone info rather than date time object are workable there. And this same thing are applicable too when i sending back time information from server to client. Need to send a specific string format rather than date time object. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .Net Web API as backend, you can config the timezone in Web API WebApiconfig.cs like below. It will serialize the time in UTC.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
}
```

Comment: Or use  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind;        //Time zone information should be  preserved when converting.

Answer (score 2):

So if you are using html5 datetime,then you can change it to datetime-local

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

This will give you datetime without the timezone info.

Here is an example.

```js
var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="datetime-local"]');
dateControl.value = '2017-06-01T08:30';

let btn = document.getElementById('btns');
let inp = document.getElementById('party');
let dv = document.getElementById('displayValue');
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  dv.innerText = inp.value;
});
```

```html
<label for="party">Enter a date and time for your party booking:</label>
<input id="party" type="datetime-local" name="partydate" value="2017-06-01T08:30">

<button type="submit" id="btns">Check Value</button>

<div id="displayValue">
  
</div>
```

Code snippet is just to give you an idea on how to use datetime-local.
If you are using angular 2/4, then you can directly bind ngModel to a variable as you would do generally to get the value.