# Display only utc using moment

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, momentjs

I need to display only the UTC Date and Time,

I am using this

```
moment.utc();
```

But it is considering my system time. I don't want to consider my system time. I just plainly want to print the UTC Time, How can i do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you looking for `moment.utc().format()`? Use [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to print the value of a moment object.

Comment: Where is the code? How are you creating the moment.js object?

Comment: Have you considered `new Date().toISOString()`?