# Date.getUTCDate() returns different results in different timezones - Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, utc

Javascript's `Date()` object is driving me crazy. I am trying to get the current UTC date (`mm/dd/yyyy`). I need the date to be the same anywhere in the world. So, to do that, I used the UTC methods like the `(new Date()).getUTCDate())` method. However recently, when a user complained, I discovered that the value returned was not the same everywhere in the world.

I need a definite way to get the CURRENT date (not past) according to universal time.

`(new Date()).getTime()` does not work for me as it returns it in milliseconds.

My code:

```js
function getToday() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getUTCDate();
    var mm = today.getUTCMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getUTCFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }

    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy
    return today;
}

console.log(getToday());
```

EDIT:

I contacted this user and told him to basically execute `(new Date()).getUTCDate())`. His was off by a day (Correct answer is 27)

[image: info]

In addition, his timezone offset was 180

[image: offset]

He is using Chrome on a Windows computer (I dont know what version)

EDIT2:

I just did some math, and I found something strange.

My user said that he had problems at 12:00PM every day when the day changes. He told me he had problems at 9:53PM for my time. Knowing that he has a timezone offset of 180 minutes, and I have a timezone offset of 240, I can calculate his time at that moment by doing `myTime + offsetDifference`. That however (`((9*60 + 53) + (240 - 180)) / 60`) equals to be about 11PM. So, his PC time MUST be backwards of 1 hour.

He could have possibly manually set his time, with his timezone wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178827/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-date-getutcdate-returns-different-results-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my user did not set his timezone but instead just set the clock. If so, as Jonathan Grey pointed out, the UTC time will be wrong even though the time checks out locally. He has fixed his timezone and it works out.

In addition, as Phil pointed out, if one wants any reliable universally standardized time, one must use a trusted backend where the time will always be correct. For that, I have also found a site called the [World Clock API](http://worldclockapi.com/). But, as I noticed, for a reliable service with guarantees that it will be up whenever your site is up, you must integrate it into your server. A simple way would be to use PHP's time() method, and calculating  the offset relative to the client's time.

Comment: Nice detective work. You can easily create a UTC `DateTime` instance in PHP, so long as the server time configuration is correct ;)

Comment: *Date.UTC* uses the host system settings to calculate the current UTC date and time, represented as milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). If the system settings are wrong, so will the resulting UTC values. Unfortunately though, I think this question is OT here. :-/