# How to convert UTC Timestamp to DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

Our codes are done on C#. However, I use javascript for e2e tests.
For a particular variable, it is based on `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` . It used to be based on `DateTime.UtcNow`

My previous js script just simply use the following declaration:

```
const date = new Date();
const dateNow = date.toISOString();
```

This is based on a suggested solution in this thread: [How do I get a UTC Timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756120/how-do-i-get-a-utc-timestamp-in-javascript)

I need the dateNow on a string format based on UTC Ticks.

Comment: What are "UTC Ticks"? *Date.now()* returns a time value in milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, which is a commonly used epoch. To get a value in integer seconds just divide by 1,000: `secs = Date.now() / 1000 |  0`.

Comment: If you have a time value in seconds that is an offset from the ECMAScript epoch, then `new Date(secs * 1e3).toISOString()` will do the job. PS. many of the answers at the link you provided are wrong or misleading.

Comment: I used this and seem to work fine. Thanks.