# Convert ISO time stamp into UTC time stamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp, utc

- Given-2020-11-23T04:08:22.361Z.
- Expected-Sep 08, 2020 09:24:05 UTC. (sample)

I have tried using .toUTCString() in javascript it returned "Mon, 23 Nov 2020 04:08:22 GMT"
Is there any other way to get the exact same format as expected

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756189/3266552

Comment: @manu in the link which u shared were all using newDate() , in my case i have different dates in the given format and i want to convert to expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)
It has an extensive set of methods for dates and time.

You can install it using

```
npm install moment
```

and then import in the file you need it in like

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Use can use then make use of utc parser to parse your date to required format

```
moment.utc().format(<date>)
```