# JQuery Full Calendar date format

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Im using JQuery Full Calendar Plugin. Code:

```
     $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
        ** options **
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/myloader/',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                    end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
                }
       *** more stuff
     });
```

now on myloader php side when i try to get start and end dates here is what i get:

```
var_dump(date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $_GET['start']), date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $_GET['end']));
```

this returns:

```
string(19) "01/27/2013 06:00:00"
string(19) "03/10/2013 06:00:00"
```

why is it **6:00:00** ? i want it to be **00:00:00** for start and **23:59:59** for end

I know i can hack through it using PHP but is there a reason why full calendar returns such date?

If i use PHP i can get desired results using:

```
$start = strtotime(date('m/d/Y', $start) . ' 00:00:00');
$end = strtotime(date('m/d/Y', $end) . ' 23:59:59');
```

but i dont want to do it on PHP side is there a way full calendar to give correct time?
If its a timezone issue how can it be fixed?

thanks

Comment: time zone differences. what exactly are you sending across in the `start` and `end` parameters?

Comment: getTime gets the time from your computer. Probably your local time zone is +6 hours.

Comment: no time on my computer is fine

Comment: FullCalendar isn't returning the 6 hour offset, the PHP date function is by using your server's default timezone.  If you just print $_GET['start'], you'll see it's a UNIX timestamp, and you can convert it to see that the time is correct.  In other words, JS is already returning a GMT time, so it's not real clear what you mean when you say you want to do it on the JS side . . .

Comment: To clarify further, .getTime() ignores timezones as it's always with respect to UTC time.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577823/if-javascript-new-date-gettime-is-run-from-2-different-timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var_dump(
   date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime(date("m/d/Y",(int)$_GET['start'])), 
   date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime(date("m/d/Y",(int)$_GET['end']))
);
```

Comment: that actually fixes it but for end it gets 00:00:00 instead of 23:59:59 but how does converting to int fix it can you explain?

Comment: It is not the int that does anything, it is the date("d/m/Y" and strtotime that fixes it.

Comment: IT does, but your php file handles the data right? So you can fix it in php