# displaying countdown in different time zones

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm running a countdown timer for use in 3 timezones (GMT,PT,EST) and i need it to sync so the timer ends at the same time for each timezone. This is my code below. This is time sensitive (no pun) so thanks in advance!

```
     <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 17, 2023 20:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: What is the time the countdown should end at? If it is `Nov 17, 2023 20:00:00`, how do you get that value and in what timezone is it?

Comment: @Titus it should end 8pm GMT and when viewed in the other time zones should Calculate to end in sync with gmt 8pm. I realise I didn’t include a time zone aha

Comment: In that case, you can use SallPepperZ's suggestion but instead of `UTC` add `GMT+0000` to the date string.

Answer (score 0):

The Unix epoch (what `Date.getTime()` returns) is a timezone-agnostic value. The reason that your code is getting differences between timezones is the way you construct the date. If you specify a timezone in your date string, it will be mapped to the same unix timestamp no matter what timezone it is run in.

```js
console.log("Old", new Date("Nov 17, 2023 20:00:00").getTime())     // Changes based on timezone
console.log("New", new Date("Fri Nov 17 2023 20:00:00 GMT+0000").getTime()) // Will always return 1700251200000
```

`new Date().getTime()` will not be affected by timezones either, see [If javascript "(new Date()).getTime()" is run from 2 different Timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577823/if-javascript-new-date-gettime-is-run-from-2-different-timezones)

Per the comment from @RobG, you should change the way the dates are written to match the EMCAScript specification, so that different Javascript implementations are guaranteed to parse correctly

Comment: "Nov 17, 2023 20:00:00" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Adding " UTC" to specify an offset is similarly problematic. In a supported format it would be "Fri Nov 17 2023 20:00:00 GMT+0000".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RobG, I've updated my answer to include that.